# Converting special characters in php

Tags: php, html, character

I want to create a folder with the following name:

1.Visit to L’Aventure Du Sucre Museum and Factory

2.Visit to Vallée des Couleurs

but I am getting :

1. Visit to Lâ€™Aventure Du Sucre Museum and Factory
2. Visit to VallÃ©e des Couleurs

how to deal with these special characters ? I know it is a well-known issue but I can't make it works please help

here is my code :

```
$Title = "Visit to L’Aventure Du Sucre Museum and Factory";

mkdir('uploadImage/'. $Title, 0777, true);
```

Comment: You should change your naming of the directories. For example you could md5 the title so it will only contain characters and numbers and no special characters.

Comment: Does your OS support multi byte character sets? What OS are you running

Comment: I am running Windows 7 Proffessional 64-bit

Comment: I can't md5 the title Manuel because I need the name for future use

Comment: what you're trying to do isn't a good idea and for many reasons. However, what I see here is an encoding problem.

Comment: The title value is obtain from a form input , I tried to use htmlspecialchars_decode but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to slugify your directory names

```
function slugify($text){
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');

  // remove duplicate -
  $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  return $text;
}

$Title = "Visit to L’Aventure Du Sucre Museum and Factory";
$Title = slugify($Title)
mkdir('uploadImage/'. $Title, 0777, true);
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I thought it would be more simple